# style file path

Tags: packages, installing

I have put the style file in `localtexmf` folder in `c:`

for example:

`\usepackage{mathtime}`
`mathtime` package called in `c:\localtexmf` folder.

Its compiling.

If we put the `mathtime` style file in tex file directory. the `mathtime` package called in
same folder path. We need not want this.

We need
if we put the `mathtime` package in same tex file loaction. We need not want to call this package. Only we need the package from `c:\localtexmf`. 
How to fix the path for style files.

Comment: Possible related question: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

Comment: The rule for finding style files is the same as for all tex input files. This is dependent on the implementation, so you need to tell us what TeX implementation you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand.  It seems that you have two copies of the style file, one in `C:\localtexmf` and one in the same directory as the `.tex` file and that you want the `C:\localtexmf` one to be the one that is used.  Is that correct?  If so, the answer that seems easiest is to delete the copy in the directory with the `.tex` file, otherwise I suspect that you will have to change some environment variables to override the normal search path for style files.

Comment: We have fixed the style file in the localtexmf folder. If anybody use the file in the same diectory as the .tex file. While compile we take the same folder style file.

Comment: So you want to be sure that any user who loads the `mathtime` package uses the _system_ one, even if they've installed a copy in the same directory as the `.tex` file.  One way to do that would be to alter the search order that TeX uses, but I don't know how to do that for one specific file only and wouldn't recommend doing it for arbitrary files.

Answer (score 2):

It should be (for windows): `localtexmf\tex\latex\`

Comment: Yes. The packages or classes must be in some sub directory of TeX tree structure called as TDS-compliant directory. :-)